# Why is byte map faster than bit map?

Tags: java, algorithm, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot, garbage

I have read the The Garbage Collection Handbook. It says when doing card table,they use bytemap instead of bitmap, and said it is faster than bitmap, is it due to  high speed cache line ? But as what i know ,the cache line normally is 64 bytes, if we make change on byte, race contention still exists , other cpu will still make the line invalidate ,it is the same as bit map ,anyone can help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got the context right but in general:

1. **bit map access**

   requires address manipulation and read write of the whole BYTE/WORD/... as most architectures does not support bit read/write memory access.

   So for 8 bit bit map like:

   ```
   BYTE map[];
   ```

   the code for read it is:

   ```
   readed_bit=(map[bit>>3]>>(bit&7))&1;
   ```

   set:

   ```
   map[bit>>3]|=1<<(bit&7);
   ```

   clear:

   ```
   map[bit>>3]&=255^(1<<(bit&7));
   ```

   where `bit` is the bit you want to access. As you can see there is masking and bit shifts needed.
2. **BYTE map access**

   this can be accessed directly on most architectures

   ```
   readed_byte=map[byte];
   ```

   set:

   ```
   map[byte]=1;
   ```

   clear:

   ```
   map[byte]=0;
   ```

   Where `byte` is BYTE you want to access. As you can see the memory space is wasted if just boolean value is stored in single BYTE.

So unless you got specific **HW** designed to work with bit maps and planes then BYTE maps are faster ... but to every rule there is an exception so there are algorithms where you already got the masked address and bit masks in such cases bit maps are faster or as fast as byte maps ...

Comment: I don’t think that the masking and shifting matters that much, most CPUs can do that in parallel. What matters most, is that `|=` and `&=` imply reading the value, updating it, and writing it back, which, of course, is more expensive than just writing `1` or `0` to the location. Especially when the read-modify-write cycle must be atomic on SMP machines. While races on a cache line may still exist, the CPU will sync the line only when it actually happens, while the bit operations must be atomic in advance, just because there *might* be a race…

Comment: @Holger The memory address is dependent on bit address manipulation so it must be computed before use which makes it non parallelizable. but you're right the double access (if not a special architecture used like logic unit cell grid) is what slows this the most ...

Comment: There are CPUs doing all the arithmetic in one cycle. That’s similar to “CompressedOOPs” where all object references have to get shifted to the left for accessing the memory. That can be done in an early pipeline stage not affecting the performance of the actual operation.

Comment: Um, no, unless you have very specific hardware, bit access will be orders of magnitude faster because you are utilizing your cache 7x more efficiently. Unless of course, your whole problem fits in the cache exclusively.

Comment: @Holger,it's the second time you answer my question ,thank you so much ,i think what you are saying is correct, but is there any book we can refer to know much more detail about it.